# Short Casting Error in C#

Tags: c#, casting, short

I am trying to get short variables value from my database and need to cast it but it gives an casting error at debugging how can I solve this problem ?Can you help me?

```
    obj_OBJimagegallery.watermark =String.IsNullOrEmpty((dr["watermark"]).ToString()) ? null : (short?)(dr["watermark"]);
```

Comment: InvalidCastException error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem using such an conversion

```
     (short?)(Convert.ToInt16(dr["watermark"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use method, instead of cast

```
Int16.TryParse Method (String, Int16%)
```

There is usage

```
short result;

if(Int16.TryParse Method ((dr["watermark"].ToString(), out result) == false)
{
//fail
}

obj_OBJimagegallery.watermark = result;// <- you have there parsed value
```

Comment: probablly dr["watermark"] is type of bool, you can not cast it to short! What is type of obj_OBJimagegallery.watermark??

Comment: it is short the problem is diffrent I think and it is tiny in db

Comment: try use method bool.TryParse, var result must be declared as bool

Comment: I answered look at bottom :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
short? s = String.IsNullOrEmpty((dr["watermark"]).ToString()) ? null : (short?)short.Parse(dr["watermark"].ToString());
```